# What are the names/meanings of the 256 3-variable Boolean operators?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

With 2 variables there are 16 Boolean operators each of which has names and meanings - AND, OR, XOR, NAND, NOR, IF etc
With 3 variables there are 256 possibilities. Some are the same as the 2- variable (eg AND or OR), some are extensions (eg IF a THEN b ELSE c); some may be different.
Does anyone know of a source, on the web or in a book, which tabulates and names all these possibilities?

Thanks

John

Comment: [16 Boolean Functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BooleanFunction.html). Just like in the article, these would be called $F_n, 1\le n\le 256$

Comment: If there is such a list of names, it's perhaps useless as no-one would remember all those names. And then you could ask for the names of the operations of arity $4, 5, \ldots$

Comment: There is a **classification** of all boolean functions. They form something called [Post's lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_lattice). The lattice has quite a complicated structure.